# android memory consumption

Tags: android

I have many pictures in my @drawable directory which are connected to xml layout via background property:

i.e
`<ImageButton android:background="@drawable/background1" ... />`

I have many activities, so, when activity is destroyed (BACK is pressed), the heap isn't freed. So, the question is:

Does android load everything in the memory once and make heap free only when application is destroyed? How I can prevent in this case memory consumption ? Only through image compression or dynamically loading background and images?

Comment: I'd wager that if you don't use a resource it never gets loaded into memory ...

Comment: I know this. But when it is used and loaded, memory isn't freed when activity is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I think Android has a its `own garbage collector`, but for `proceed it its take sometimes` instead of relevent momory as the object is not in use. And whenver the `bitmap is created its memory occupied in native heap` and **heap garbage collector is to lazzy.**

So if possible `use dynamic Image loading` instead of static, and try to **use your own recycler or freed the memory of your bitmap**.

EDIT:

> The gc() does not handle so-called short lived objects as fast as we
>   would like.

**Keep the number of view objects at a stable level*, and recycle them instead of destroying and creating new ones.**

A nice post of [Avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) by Roman Guys refer it.

If I am wrong please let me know. And please share some more information on this.

Thanks.